# Kendo grid is still showing last record after delete?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid where i am deleting row so when user click i am calling method `deleteOwner` , once each item is deleted i am resetting grid dataSource and refershing grid so its deleting all records except the last. Actually it deleted the record because array `selectedOwners` is showing empty but kendo grid is still displaying the last record even afte rrefresh of dataSource.

Any idea what is going wrong here ?

ctrl.js

```
 $scope.deleteOwner = function(dataItem) {
                   angular.forEach(selectedOwners, function(owner, $index) {
                     if (owner.workerKey === dataItem.workerKey) {
                         selectedOwners.splice($index, 1);
                         console.log('ANGULAR FOREACH',JSON.stringify(selectedOwners));
                         return;
                     }
                     var selectedOwnersData =  new kendo.data.DataSource({
                       data:  selectedOwners,
                       pageSize : 5
                       });
                     $scope.selectedOwnerGridOptions.dataSource = selectedOwnersData;
                     $scope.selectedOwnerGrid = new Date().getTime();
                   });
                 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead of selectedOwners.splice($index, 1);

```html
$scope.selectedOwners.splice($scope.selectedOwners.indexOf(dataItem), 1);
```

Comment: its not a $scope variable why we are assigning it to $scope.

Comment: did you mean to say `selectedOwners.splice(selectedOwners.indexOf(dataItem), 1);`